# Get the "CONNECTEDIDNUMBER" during a running call with TAPI3

Tags: c#, tapi

I'm in need to get the number my phone is connected to during the call. TAPI3Lib (that one for c#) only provides events and I can't trigger them on my own. There are only events, that trigger when I ... well when I trigger something.
So is there no possible way to get any info with an application when I start it up while I am already on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

In TAPI 3 this is possible via the ITAddress::EnumerateCalls method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms728230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

But I do not know if TAPI3Lib exposes this functionality

Comment: But the documentation says "This method is provided for C and C++ applications", and this question is tagged as C#.

Comment: TAPI 3 is a COM-based API, so C# will need to use a wrapper (usually C/C++ based). The documentation also links through to the Visual Basic style function in the next sentence. My point remains the same: yes, TAPI 3 can do this, but if TAPI3Lib exposes the functionality, i do not know.

Comment: I won't look back into my code, but I couldn't figure anything out to solve my problem. I ended up writing a little background service, that uses these events. That's one more service "just to help the developer" but as long as our customers don't realize that, it seems to be fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

TAPI3 offers a method called get_CallInfoString to retrieve data like the connected number.

In your case, you need to find the correct ITCallInfo-Object associated with your call and call get_CallInfoString on it.

```
callInfo.get_CallInfoString(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNUMBER);
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms729304(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.